# Show HTML elements in JSON with Angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I am new in angular js, I am trying to format a json data with angular js.

Here is my json data

```
 [
   {"field_add_link": "<a href=\"/drupal3/drupal3/\">Home</a>"},
   {"field_add_link": "<a href=\"/drupal3/drupal3/about\">About Us</a>"}
]
```

here is my conroller

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);
myApp.controller('myController',function($scope, $http) {
   $http.get('http://localhost/drupal3/menu')
   .then(function(response) {
       $scope.links = response;
    });
});
```

and finally here is how i am fetching the json data with angular

```
<div class="col-md-8 content"  ng-controller ="myController">
    <div class="col-md-12" ng-repeat="link in links" ng-bind-html="links">
        <p>{{ link.field_add_link }}</p>
    </div>      
</div>
```

no output was shown after this, giving an error `Error: [$sce:unsafe] Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context.` in the browser's console

but when I used `ng-bind-html="links[0].field_add_link` instead of `ng-bind-html="links"` and `<p>{{ link[0].field_add_link }}</p>` instead of `<p>{{ link.field_add_link }}</p>`

then i get `<a href="/drupal3/drupal3/">Home</a>` as output *'without interpreting the tag'*

Pls, how do I go about this?

Comment: use [`$sce.trustAsHtml(...)`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#trustAsHtml) to trust your compiled links. (Also you need to assign `response.data`)

Comment: and read about `ngSanitize` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize

Answer (score 0):

First of all you dont need the `ng-bind-html` attribute on your `div` with `ng-repeat`. It should be on your `p` tag. Second, you need to bind `link` (the current element of the `ng-repeat`-loop) not `links` (the array). Although you need to look into the error [[$sce:unsafe](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)]. HTMl can only be bind to an element-body if it is trusted. For that you need to have, for example, a filter.

```
myApp.filter ('to_trusted', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
    return function (text) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml (text);
    };
}]);

<div class="col-md-8 content"  ng-controller ="myController">
    <div class="col-md-12" ng-repeat="link in links">
        <p ng-bind-html="link.field_add_link | to_trusted"></p>
    </div>      
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot man...i tried this but i am having an error `Error: [$sce:insecurl] Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to move your `ng-bind-html` from div to `<p>` like following code.

```
  <p ng-bind-html="link.field_add_link"></p>
```

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);
myApp.controller('myController', function($scope, $http) {
var data = [{"field_add_link": "<a href=\"/drupal3/drupal3/\">Home</a>"},
    {"field_add_link": "<a href=\"/drupal3/drupal3/about\">About Us</a>"}];
  $scope.links = data;
 //For demo, removed the http call
});
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="col-md-8 content" ng-controller="myController">
    <div class="col-md-12" ng-repeat="link in links">
      <p ng-bind-html="link.field_add_link"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this worked but when i am using the `http call` it is not working

Comment: it is showing this error in the console  
`Error: [$sce:insecurl] Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy.`